# Pass result of a query into stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that accepts three parameters.

Is it possible to call this stored procedure with a query as input?

As an example, I have `tableA`.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA 

| A | B | C |
|---+---+---|
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
```

Now, is there a way that I can call

```
EXEC sp_name (SELECT * FROM TABLEA)
```

so that the stored procedure will execute for each row?

My reasoning behind this is I have a stored procedure that needs to be called for multiple rows. I can write a script to do this, but want to know if its possible to do it with TSQL.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! That way, you don't need any of the messy `<br/>` tags either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is to create your 2nd stored procedure as a user-defined function instead. Then you can call it in this way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA
CROSS APPLY dbo.yourUserFunction(column1, column2, etc)
```

Or, there may be a way to combine both stored procedures into one set, but I'd have to see what was in the 2nd one you are calling.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is assuming that the T-SQL is running on SQL SERVER 2008 and above

1. Create a Table Type variable , This needs to be done only once
   `USE YOURDBNAME;`
   Go
   `Create TYPE TableAType as Table
   (A int null,B int null, C int null);`
   This creates a table type variable in user-defined table types in the DB that you are currently using.
2. In your Stored proc, Declare a variable of this table type. and Populate it with the contents from table A. Example:

   ```
   Create Procedure MyStoredProcedure1 AS Declare @TableB as TableAType; 
   Insert into @TableB(A,B,C) Select A,B,C from TableA;
   ```
3. Create your Main Stored Proc

   ```
   Create Procedure MyStoredProcedure2
   @TVP TableAType READONLY
   as 
   EXEC sp_Name @TVP;
   ```

This should do the work for you,
For further reference , please see the link below#
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes, but your call to the sproc is badly formatted.

```
Exec sp_name 'SELECT * FROM TABLEA'
```

or

```
Exec sp_name @sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM TABLEA'
```

That said, what you are trying to do may not be a good idea.