# Using Same Stored Procedure for Inserting List of Values and Query Results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I have a stored procedure to insert a row, with a list of values which came as input parameters, into a table (`tmp`).

This table mirrors another table (`data`), and I'm looking for a way to use the same SP to insert a row from `data` into `tmp`.

I've seen [Pass result of a query into stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643289/pass-result-of-a-query-into-stored-procedure), but I can't put `INSERT` in a UDF.

Is there an easy way, not requiring

- a query which puts all the values into variables and sends the variables?
- a table-typing or other additions to our already-too-full database

**Edit** The desired result would be a way to write something like

```
EXEC sp_insert (SELECT c1,c2,c3 FROM data)
```

Comment: A trick we used to do a few jobs ago was to have the stored procedure insert from a temp table, so instead of passing in parameters you have it check if the temp table exist and if it does insert what is in it. This way you can choose either the data table as source or some other  source

Comment: So you have an SP that accepts a bunch of parameters and inserts them into table `tmp`.  And you want this same SP to insert a row into `tmp` that is selected from `data` instead of inserting the passed-in parameters?  1) is that correct?  2) how will the SP know whether it should insert the passed-in parameters or insert a row that is selected from `data`?

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question, it sounds like you just need to do an INSERT..SELECT from data to tmp.

Comment: Can you please be a little more explicit / clearer with exactly what you are trying to do? What is stopping you from inserting into `tmp` directly from an select from `data`?

Comment: @DeadZone, 1. correct, 2. that's the question, or, if I can pass it in a way that he'll think it's parameters

Comment: Let me elaborate on question #2... Is the SP supposed to determine (use some intelligence and decide) what to do, or is the caller supposed to tell (dictate to the SP) the SP what to do?  If the latter, simply add a `bit` parameter to your SP to toggle between inserting parameter values and inserting selected rows.  If the former, then wrap your SP in a big IF statement... If X then Insert parameters ELSE Insert from `data`.  (If there's something we're all missing, please elaborate on where the hang-up lies.)

Comment: @deadzone, neither. I've actually been hoping the SP could be oblivious to the whole thing

Comment: I think you're going to need to edit your question to be more explicit about the exact nature of the problem.  I don't think it's clear what you're looking for.

Comment: I've added to the question. It's similar to what appears in the linked question

Comment: `EXEC sp_insert (SELECT c1,c2,c3 FROM data)` you can't get this because `EXEC` allows only `value/@variable/DEFAULT`. Without using variable to store temporary result it is not possible to use syntax like that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use variable table as the parameter for the SP (search for this)
It needs to define user defined table type , but I'm using this method. 
Table used as a parameter can get values from inserting or selecting from other table.

```
alter procedure sp_insert
@table your_table_type readonly
AS
BEGIN
--here you take a row (maybe the only one) from @table and insert it to TMP
END
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for your answer, it's written well, but I specified I was looking for an answer not using this option. Keep up the good work.